# FastAPI, asyncpg (postgres) and Docker: wsocket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: python, docker, sqlalchemy, fastapi, asyncpg

I'm aware that the error I'm about to describe is disgustingly generic, but I'm days into debugging and getting nowhere...

I'm running a fastapi application in docker, using the library `fastapi-users`, which uses `sqlalchemy==1.4` and `asyncpg`. My database interface is based in this file:

```py
from typing import AsyncGenerator

from fastapi import Depends
from fastapi_users.db import SQLAlchemyBaseUserTable, SQLAlchemyUserDatabase
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import DeclarativeMeta, declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from backend.models.user import UserDB
from backend.core.settings.config import settings

Base: DeclarativeMeta = declarative_base()


class UserTable(Base, SQLAlchemyBaseUserTable):
    pass


DATABASE_URL = "postgresql+asyncpg://ubuntu:secrets@app-db:5432/app_db"


engine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL)
async_session_maker = sessionmaker(engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)


async def create_db_and_tables():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)


async def get_async_session() -> AsyncGenerator[AsyncSession, None]:
    async with async_session_maker() as session:
        yield session


async def get_user_db(session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session)):
    yield SQLAlchemyUserDatabase(UserDB, session, UserTable)
```

Then I spin up the app using this docker-compose setup:

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:
  # PostgreSQL development environment database
  app-db:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ubuntu
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secrets
      POSTGRES_DB: app_db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"


  # FastAPI backend
  app-backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
    depends_on:
      - app-db
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    stop_signal: SIGINT
    command: uvicorn backend.main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
    environment:
      PYTHONPATH: .
      BASE_ENVIRONMENT: prod
```

The database is created okay, and the app starts up, but when I go to create the tables in my `main.py` file:

```py
async def create_db_and_tables():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)

@app.on_event("startup")
async def on_startup():
    await create_db_and_tables()
```

the whole thing blows up and the tables are not created:

```sh
 INFO:     Started server process [8]
app-backend_1   | INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
app-backend_1   | ERROR:    Traceback (most recent call last):
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 621, in lifespan
app-backend_1   |     async with self.lifespan_context(app):
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 518, in __aenter__
app-backend_1   |     await self._router.startup()
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 598, in startup
app-backend_1   |     await handler()
app-backend_1   |   File "/ubuntu/./backend/main.py", line 26, in on_startup
app-backend_1   |     await create_db_and_tables()
app-backend_1   |   File "/ubuntu/./backend/db.py", line 24, in create_db_and_tables
app-backend_1   |     async with engine.begin() as conn:
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/base.py", line 60, in __aenter__
app-backend_1   |     return await self.start(is_ctxmanager=True)
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/engine.py", line 596, in start
app-backend_1   |     await self.conn.start(is_ctxmanager=is_ctxmanager)
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/engine.py", line 155, in start
app-backend_1   |     await (greenlet_spawn(self.sync_engine.connect))
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 134, in greenlet_spawn
app-backend_1   |     result = context.throw(*sys.exc_info())
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/future/engine.py", line 406, in connect
app-backend_1   |     return super(Engine, self).connect()
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3210, in connect
app-backend_1   |     return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 96, in __init__
app-backend_1   |     else engine.raw_connection()
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3289, in raw_connection
app-backend_1   |     return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3256, in _wrap_pool_connect
app-backend_1   |     return fn()
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 310, in connect
app-backend_1   |     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 868, in _checkout
app-backend_1   |     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 476, in checkout
app-backend_1   |     rec = pool._do_get()
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
app-backend_1   |     self._dec_overflow()
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
app-backend_1   |     compat.raise_(
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
app-backend_1   |     raise exception
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
app-backend_1   |     return self._create_connection()
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 256, in _create_connection
app-backend_1   |     return _ConnectionRecord(self)
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 371, in __init__
app-backend_1   |     self.__connect()
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 666, in __connect
app-backend_1   |     pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
app-backend_1   |     compat.raise_(
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
app-backend_1   |     raise exception
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 661, in __connect
app-backend_1   |     self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 590, in connect
app-backend_1   |     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 597, in connect
app-backend_1   |     return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 777, in connect
app-backend_1   |     await_only(self.asyncpg.connect(*arg, **kw)),
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 76, in await_only
app-backend_1   |     return current.driver.switch(awaitable)
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 129, in greenlet_spawn
app-backend_1   |     value = await result
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 2085, in connect
app-backend_1   |     return await connect_utils._connect(
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 895, in _connect
app-backend_1   |     raise last_error
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 881, in _connect
app-backend_1   |     return await _connect_addr(
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 781, in _connect_addr
app-backend_1   |     return await __connect_addr(params, timeout, True, *args)
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 825, in __connect_addr
app-backend_1   |     tr, pr = await compat.wait_for(connector, timeout=timeout)
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asyncpg/compat.py", line 66, in wait_for
app-backend_1   |     return await asyncio.wait_for(fut, timeout)
app-backend_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/tasks.py", line 479, in wait_for
app-backend_1   |     return fut.result()
app-backend_1   |   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 691, in _create_ssl_connection
app-backend_1   |     tr, pr = await loop.create_connection(
app-backend_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1026, in create_connection
app-backend_1   |     infos = await self._ensure_resolved(
app-backend_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1405, in _ensure_resolved
app-backend_1   |     return await loop.getaddrinfo(host, port, family=family, type=type,
app-backend_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 861, in getaddrinfo
app-backend_1   |     return await self.run_in_executor(
app-backend_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
app-backend_1   |     result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
app-backend_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 954, in getaddrinfo
app-backend_1   |     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
app-backend_1   | socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
app-backend_1   | 
app-backend_1   | ERROR:    Application startup failed. Exiting.
```

So I've got this `socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution` error, related for some reason to an SSL issue (`_create_ssl_connection`?), even though I'm not trying to create an SSL connection, or do anything beyond running the app at `localhost:8000`.

**The app and database work fine locally if I don't use Docker.**

Any advice?

Comment: I see that error quite often with my Ubuntu VMs trying to access machines by name on my local network. The fix (for me) is to delete the `/etc/resolv.conf` symlink and replace it with an actual file containing the single line `nameserver 192.168.0.1` (which is my actual DNS server).

Comment: possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/q/907246/323236